# UWP:- How to refer a code behind of a resource dictionary that exists in another assembly in a XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Accessing from the same assembly:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/test/testing.xaml"/>
    <templates:testing/> <!- This works -->
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Accessing a resource from another assembly:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Components/test/testing.xaml"/>
    <templates:testing/> <!- This doesn't work-->
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML seems fine,

Perhaps is it linked to your project settings.
When you create your assembly, for xaml resources you should use Windows Runtime Component

[image]

And in project's properties check that your namespace is "Components"